# How do I use an issued API key in my python 3 script to bypass the request limiter?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain.info, api, python

I got an API key from blockchain.info to bypass the request limiter, but I don't know how to use it and I can't find any relevant info online.

```
 url = "https://blockchain.info/rawblock/" + str(s)
        usock = urlopen(url)
        data = usock.read()
```

where variable s is the block height.

As the python blockchain.info API states:

https://blockchain.info/rawaddr/$bitcoin_address
Address can be base58 or hash160
Optional limit parameter to show n transactions e.g. &limit=50 (Default: 50, Max: 50)

BUT it also states:

Request limits and API keys
In order to prevent abuse some API methods require an API key approved with some basic contact information and a description of its intended use. Please request an API key here.

The same API key can be used to bypass the request limiter.

However, I don't know how to incorporate it in the function.

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [need to get an "api_code"](https://github.com/blockchain/api-v1-client-python#request-limits-and-api-keys), then use that when making calls.

You can use their official [python client](https://github.com/blockchain/api-v1-client-python/blob/master/docs/blockexplorer.md).

Comment: Hi Jonathan...I have the api key (i assume it s the same as api code you re referring to). 

I have been using the python client and getting the data I want but the issue is that for a certain wallet address I can get only 50 transactions of let s say 800.

My question is how can I incorporate the API key in the python script and download all of the transactions instead of just 50.

Comment: @AndreasManousakis It looks like you can just add the `api_code` as a parameter: https://github.com/blockchain/api-v1-client-python/blob/52ea562f824f04303e75239364e06722bec8620f/blockchain/blockexplorer.py#L11